# Best way to read a user on init

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter

I have a problem, when I go to the view of the home in my app I have to instantiate a user from firebase, at the time of obtaining the name is null.
I do not know how to bring a user and expect it to load asynchronously because the initial state of the widget does not allow the asynchronous tag.
If I assign it to 'Then' it is also null

Thank you!

```
//Home Widget State

User currentUser = widget.userController.getCurrentUser(); //ERROR


//CONTROLLER

Future<User> getCurrentUser() async {

    User user =  await _db.collection('users').document(await getCurrentUserUID()).get().then((snapshot){
      return User.fromJson(snapshot.data);
    });

    print(user.toString());

    return user;

  }
```

Comment: why it is tagged with `ios`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're looking for something like this?

```
  Map _userProfile;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged.listen((user) {
      if(user != null) _getUserProfile(user.uid);
    });
  }

  void getUserProfile(String uid) {
    _db.collection('users').document(uid).get().then((snapshot){
       setState(() {
         _userProfile = snapshot.data;
       });
    });
  }
```